# in scala , how do I filter after zip two arrays

Tags: arrays, scala, filter, zip, multidimensional-array

```
 def clu(allcenter:Array[Int], data:Array[Array[Double]], cnum : Int) = {
     val alldata = (data, allcenter).zipped.map { case (a, b) => b.toDouble +: a}
```

after this I want to filter alldata's  first element and get the remain element

like this:

```
alldata.fliter(_._1 == 10).map(case(a,b,c) => (b,c)) //it's way in tuple
```

how can I  rewrite above statement in array way?
thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
alldata
  .filter(_(0) == 10)
  .map {
    case Array(a, b, c) => (b, c) // from array to tuple
  }
```

However, you can also do both at the same time:

```
alldata collect {
  case Array(10, b, c) => (b, c)
}
```

Comment: thank you! :) then how can I  get the value b and c?

Comment: @user2956843 What do you mean?

Comment: how can I get the remain element of array 
EX. alldata(0)(0) = 10 alldata(0)(1) = 11 alldata(0)(2) = 12
and I use the above way alldata.fliter(_(0) == 10 )......
then how can I get the value 11, 12    thank you~